# Calling a webservice asynchonously

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asynchronous, synchronous

I have a method as below which fetches huge customer data from DB by a webservice. The method returns list of customers as shown below:

```
 List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();

 foreach (CustomerSummary cs in lastModifiedCustomers)
 {
    customers.Add(customerService.CallService(x => x.GetCustomerByKey(cs.Key, context)));
 }

 return customers;
```

How to call this above webservice in an asynchronous way? I cannot make any change to webservice code.

Actually fetching this huge data gives timeout error when API call is made. Is there any optimise way to do this?

Comment: use Task class.

Comment: you use `Task.Run(()=>customerService.CallService`

Comment: @Eldho The webservice method is synchronous. On doing the above change I get error as : Error CS1503 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Threading.Tasks.Task<Customer>' to 'Customer'

Comment: You need to wait for the result like ‘var cs=await task.run(()=> yourservice.method(1):’

Comment: This certanly will not change timeout error. Because in any case service hase timeout setting. If this timeout is your client application timeout then you can adjust it to bigger value.

Comment: Ideally you want to all customers by single call. Like getcustomers(list of customer id you want ).

Comment: To do this request asynchronously you can regenerate your webservice client code to be asynchronous (visual studio can do it).

Comment: Can you show your timeout error? Maybe the timeout is at db level.

Comment: I am getting 504: Gateway Timeout error

Comment: What LINQ does this generate? Maybe this can all be excuted on the database side? Your problem appears to be that you are getting a timeout, not that you want to call a web service asynchronously.

Comment: are you getting the exception on the customerService.CallService(...) call?

Comment: @Pavel Actually I do not have access to web service code. When I am running the API call from Postman, I get this error.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid when the record count increases more than 1000, I get this error.

Comment: @kanika, to summarize, you have a web service method that executes the code above. This method calls another web service to fetch records one by one. If it has to do 1000+ iterations, initial call returning timeout. Right?

Comment: If you don’t have access to the web service code there’s very little you can do.

Comment: @PavelShastov The above code is called by an API. This is not a web service method. The above code then calls a web service which gives error when records more than 1000 are returned

Comment: Instead of using for each , try to break the records into sets and call the web service for each set. That will make sure you won't get timeout.

Comment: Don't use Task.Run() because it is for CPU-Intensive code and your code is an I/O operation (For more information, click here: https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Three-Essential-Tips-for-Async/Tip-2-Distinguish-CPU-Bound-work-from-IO-bound-work)

Comment: @Atk Can you please tell me how can we follow this approach

Comment: @kanika Check my answer below. Try with 1000 records first, if it still shows timeout, reduce to 500 and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
int size=1000;
int iterations = (lastModifiedCustomers.Items.Count/size)+1;

List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();
for(int i=1;i<iterations;i++)
{

 foreach (CustomerSummary cs in lastModifiedCustomers.GetRange(i==1?i:(i-1)*size+1,size))
 {
    customers.Add(customerService.CallService(x => x.GetCustomerByKey(cs.Key, context)));
 }
}
 return customers;
```

Comment: @DanielBoteroCorrea Its just a workaround of the problem, It will hit the web service multiple times for the given list.

Comment: @Atk Thank you for this workaround.This is working. Only one change I did in GetRange() i.e. instead of i*size, we need to give only size, as the second parameter specifies count not the index.

Comment: @kanika Yes, I corrected it now. Kindly accept as answer and upvote.

Comment: @Atk One more thing to ask, if my records are 1001 and I have given size=100 then how it will take the last element as it will traverse through only 10 iterations.

Comment: @kanika 
int iterations = (lastModifiedCustomers.Items.Count/size)+1;
eg, 1001/100+1 which is equal to 11 iterations.

Comment: @Atk with this solution I was getting following error: Offset and length were out of bounds for the array . So I corrected it as shown in Answer below

Answer (score 0):

I was getting out of bound error by using the above solution.So I corrected it as below:

```
int size=100;
List<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();
for(int i=0;i<iterations;i+=size)
{
 foreach (CustomerSummary cs in lastModifiedCustomers.GetRange(i,Math.Min(size,lastModifiedCustomers.Count-i)))
 {
    customers.Add(customerService.CallService(x => x.GetCustomerByKey(cs.Key, context)));
 }
}
 return customers;
```

Comment: Hopefully you haven't introduced a race condition with this fix.